# how to create a 3d mosaic out of a 2d image

Tags: image, 3d-printing, 2d

i have a  mosaic image and i want to turn it into a plan object that is going to have a 3D bumps.the result is going to be printed with a 3d printer .the idea is to extract the parts of the image so i can feel them with my hands 
i still didn't try any method and i don't know where to start.
[image]

Comment: Easily 'extracting' the bumps from the image does not seem like a very realistic possibility here. There are no uniform properties in the image that could define height - the bits have different colors and brightness values. I think this might be a suitable case for the good old-fashioned loads-of-tedious-hard-work workflow. It could be loosely recreated adding arrayed cubes and sculpting to add variation in 3d, or it could be recreated as a 2d image to be used for displacement. There are repeating patterns there, so that makes things a bit easier.

Comment: i a little bit in a rush and i don't have time to recreated and sculpted .So is there any method or a software that can help me do it faster. i also heard that i can't use normal maps and textures because it's only in the software the details won't appear when i print it.

Comment: have a look at Materialize http://boundingboxsoftware.com/materialize/ it is Windows only but is free and the video tutorials show how you can create bump/height maps from photo textures.

Comment: Sadly, the lack of time in your situation does not influence the amount of available solutions to your problem. If you wish the result to have any meaningful amount of accuracy, there is not much that can be done. You could attempt to edit the brightness of the image isolating it by color in some image editing software. For example in Photoshop there is a function Image -> Adjustments -> Black and White where you can try to make the colored tiles brighter than the gaps. It will not be a very precise result. You would have to deal with shadows as well. Look into Frequency Separation techniques.

Answer (score 0):

The only automation you can have is to translate the brightness value of every pixel into a height map, setting it as texture in a displace modifier on a highly subdivided plane. The result is quite random because of the problems Martin Z said. In my example we have 1.500.000 vertices. [image]